# Perl templates with inheritance

Tags: perl, templates, inheritance

Exists in the Perl world any template system with *template inheritance*?

Just checked in the wikipedia [Comparison_of_web_template_engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines) (really incomplete list) - and here isn't listed any.

> Inheritance = Supports the ability to inherit a layout from a parent
>   template, separately overriding arbitrary sections of the parent
>   template's content.

Mean something like python's Jinja2:

```
#body.html
<body>
   {% block content %}
   <!-- the content go here -->
   {% endblock %}
</body>

#hi.html
{% extends "body.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Hi!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

rendering `hi.html` gives

```
 <body>
 <h1>Hi!</h1>
 </body>
```

Don't looking for *exact Jinja2 syntax*, simply looking for any template engine from the perl world what supports *inheritance*. (not only plain *includes* - like Template::Toolkit)

Asking here because searching CPAN is a pain for words like "template inheritance" - shows thousands modules what not related to this question.

*Ps: ... and it shouldn't be something like embedded perl - should be "user editable" allowing users builds own templates without compromise a whole system - therefore can't use Mason or HTML::Mason)*

Comment: Don't know if it supports your exact definition of template inheritance, but [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_Processing_Template_Files_and_Blocks) has some nice features for reusing components and composing templates from multiple files.

Comment: Why include/process/wrapper of Template Toolkit do not help you?

Comment: @PseftiS it is like: "Why do you uses perl objects inheritance" and not only `require '/some/file.pl'` ;) ;). Mostly the difference is only in the bless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll second the suggestion for [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aXslate).  Its syntax is even quite similar to your Jinja2 examples:

In `layouts/main.tx`:

```
...
<div id="page">
  : block sidebar -> { }
  <div id="content">
    : block header-> { <h1>Default Title</h1> }
    : block content -> { }
  </div>
</div>
...
```

In another template:

```
: cascade layouts::main
: override header -> {
<div id="header">
...
</div>
: }

: override content -> {
<div id="content-body">
...
</div>
: }
```

Comment: Thx, going to check it... ;)

Answer (score 2):

A colleague recently started using [Text::Xslate](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aXslate).

Answer (score 2):

Template::Jade, a port of [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) to perl.

### parent.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Jade template
  body.class
    p#id_name
      block content
```

### child.jade

```
extends parent

block content
  p.
    This is a test.
    This is a test.
    This is a test.
```

Answer (score 2):

[DTL::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/~hurricup/DTL-Fast/lib/DTL/Fast.pm) Is my Perl implementation of [Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/) with inheritance and other stuff.